# Spring JdbcTemplate and Threading

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Is it safe to fork off a Thread to execute an insert using a `JdbcTemplate` in Swing.

It's a logging event and as much as possible I don't want it to affect perceived performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This answer](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/16972-jdbctemplate-thread-safety) from the Spring forum says yes.t=25965

JdbcTemplate is a singleton that won't change state once it's set.

Answer (score 10):

Also note that its thread-safety is [very well explained in the Spring 3.1 reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-idioms):

**13.2.1.2 JdbcTemplate best practices**

> Instances of the JdbcTemplate class are threadsafe once configured. This is important because it means that you can configure a single instance of a JdbcTemplate and then safely inject this shared reference into multiple DAOs (or repositories). The JdbcTemplate is stateful, in that it maintains a reference to a DataSource, but this state is not conversational state.

Comment: And read carefully "once configured" bit, so don't misuse setMaxResult for limiting result set for given thread for given query, as it affects all the queries and all the threads using shared JdbcTemplate instance.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you think that it wouldn't be?

I've not used `JdbcTemplate` directly from Swing, but I have in several web applications (which have a separate thread per request) and I've never had any problems with threading issues from it. In this situation the template was configured once at application startup and repeatedly called with different parameters.

If you're worried about threading issues, you can always create a new template per logging thread...