# Thread safety in spring jdbc java

Tags: spring-mvc, scope, spring-jdbc

I have a spring MVC application in which i am using the JdbcTemplate to interact my application with DB. I autowired the JdbcTemplate in the "B" class to get its object. I also have a common class "A" which has all the static methods and i am using one of its static method from a method inside the B class. The static method is performing a SQL operation so i pass the JdbcTemplate from "B" class method to "A" class static method. It is running fine but I am worried about the thread safety. Is this code runs fine on multi threaded environment or when multiple HTTP request coming to execute the same "B" class method which has a dependency on the static method ?

I would also like to know that how a singleton scope of @controller, @repository etc can not lead to shared same data, because I am using the singleton scope and suppose if multiple request comes on a same method then there must be in mismatch between data, but it is still running fine. what is the reason behind this theory ?

Code is something like this:

```
@Repository
class B implements C{
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jTemplate;

public int bMethod(){
//method logic
String query = "Select * from test";
List<Map<String, Object>> = A.aMethod(jTemplate, query);

//One more sql operation but from local method of class
localMethod();

return 1;
}
} 


Class A{

public static List<Map<String, Object>> aMethod(JdbcTemplate jTemplate, String query){
    return jTemplate.queryForList(query);
}
}


Please avoid any syntax error and logic its just an example of how i am doing the things and clears the concept of multi threaded environment in this. Thanks
```

Comment: You don't have any shared state except for the JdbcTemplate instance, which is thread-safe. So your code is thread-safe.

Comment: I think this is duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467324/spring-jdbctemplate-and-threading

Comment: @JBNizet while you are saying not have any shared state, what does it mean ?

Comment: Thread-safety issues come up when multiple threads access mutable shared state (i.e. data) concurrently. If all threads are completely independant and don't share any state, there is no thread-safety issue.

Comment: they are sharing, suppose multiple http request comes to a same method i.e. bMethod() then its a type of shared data between many thread request, so there must be a mismatch between all thread exists as there is only one object of this class as it is singleton. @JB Nizet

Comment: A method is not data. It's not state. Calling the same method, on the same object, concurrently, doesn't cause any thread-safety issue if the method doesn't use mutable shared state. By definition, local variables in a method aren't shared between threads: each thread has its own stack.

Comment: ok, now i understand the point that is why it is recommended not to use global variables in a web application as many request can overrides them.
But i am amazed that how they just make jdbc template so thread safe that they have no effect like in global variables, even though i am making its object at class level.