# Why Spring JdbcTemplate is thread-safe?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-jdbc

I am learning how multithreading is supported by Spring. I found that Spring docs say that JdbcTemplate is [thread-safe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) once configured.
People suggest to use one instance of JdbcTemplate for the whole app as it is thread-safe (meaning there is no need to create a new instance for each class).

But when i look at the JdbcTemplate code i do not see any synchronized methods, locks or volatile variables. Also it contains a lot of instance variables. My question is how the JdbcTemplate can be thread-safe in this case?

Comment: Because there is no state being kept at the instance level and hence no need for `synchronized` methods or object locks. The instance variables you see are only delegates, for exception translation, obtaining a connection etc.

Comment: Because, once configured, if nobody tries to reconfigure it, its state never changes. No shared mutable state == thread-safe. Just like, if you safely publish a simple ArrayList and never call any method that modifies the list, even from several threads,  it's thread-safe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467324/spring-jdbctemplate-and-threading

Comment: @silfrede did you read the answers on that page ? the link in the answer marked as accepted leads to spring forum that is closed.

Comment: An accepted answer doesn't mean it is the best answer, just the answer accepted by the original poster of the question. The second answer, higher upvoted, essentially answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the snippet from Spring reference documentation under the section [JDBCTemplate Best Practices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-idioms)

> Instances of the JdbcTemplate class are thread-safe, once configured. This is important because it means that you can configure a single instance of a JdbcTemplate and then safely inject this shared reference into multiple DAOs (or repositories). The JdbcTemplate is stateful, in that it maintains a reference to a DataSource, but this state is not conversational state.

As clearly explained in the docs and you can see in the source code as well. This class does not hold any conversational state. It only has configuration information.